# Left join exclude with multiple constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to isolate customers that only had a certain type of transaction (cash, card, cheque) on any given day. They may have had multiple transactions on a date but I want to exclude those that had a certain type.

My table called transaction stores the customer number, transaction date, transaction type, amount. I want to find the customer and date if the only transaction (or transactions) are of the type 'card'.

So the following data would only return: 3456, 26/03/2018

```
+----------+------------+------+--------+
| Customer |    Date    | Type | Amount |
+----------+------------+------+--------+
|     1234 | 26/03/2018 | Card |     10 |
|     1234 | 26/03/2018 | Cash |     20 |
|     1234 | 28/03/2018 | Cash |     20 |
|     2345 | 26/03/2018 | Cash |     20 |
|     2345 | 28/03/2018 | Cash |     20 |
|     3456 | 26/03/2018 | Card |     10 |
|     3456 | 26/03/2018 | Card |     20 |
+----------+------------+------+--------+
```

This is my code but it only returns blank rows.

```
select t1.customer, t1.date
from transaction t1 
left join transaction t2 on t1.customer = t2.customer  
and t1.date = t2.date  
where t1.type = 'card' and t2.type <> 'card'  
and (t2.customer is null  and t2.date is null)  group by t1.customer, t1.date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggests aggregation and `having`:

```
select t.customer, t.date
from transaction t 
group by t.customer, t.date
having min(t.type) = max(t.type) and min(t.type) = 'card';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bd2d0d152a126285861cff0f3c1982a) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that it works.

Comment: Sorry, that is still returning nothing.

Comment: @Goolsy . . . I don't know what it returns nothing for you.  It returns exactly what you specify for the data in your question:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bd2d0d152a126285861cff0f3c1982a.

Comment: My apologies. You are correct. I'd simplified by scenario and then expanded on your suggestion incorrectly. I have it working now. Thanks.